# Randomly choose any number of elements within a given sample randomly

Tags: matlab

If I want to arbitraraly choose any number $(1\sim9)$ of arbitrarily elements within $(1\sim9)$:

Ex:
1. $n = 3$ (randomly) $\rightarrow$ choose $"1,4,9"$ (randomly & no repeat)
2. $n = 2$ (randomly) $\rightarrow$ choose $"9,10"$ (randomly & no repeat)

How to use Matlab to implement it?

1. I know  `randsample`; however, `randsample` can only choose one value randomly.
2. Use `for loop`. The bad news is this method will repeat the choice.

Any good way?

Comment: `randsample` can choose more than one element, without replacement (otherwise it would be the same as `randi`); see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = randi(9); % number of elements to pick: choose uniformly between 1 and 9
result = randsample(9, n); % pick n elements from 1,...,9 uniformly without replacement
```

Answer (score 1):

[a,b]=sort(rand(1,9));b([1 2 3])
EDIT
There are a lot more sets of five-from-nine than one-from-nine.  If you want to make all these sets equally likely, (and so choose five of them more often than one of them), you could do

result = find(rand(1,9)>0.5);

This has the disadvantage that, once in 512, you get no numbers :(

Comment: not quite exactly, it seems it cannot arbitrarily choose any number of elements because of  b([1 2 3]), in which you have to choose three elements. How to do this step automatically?

Comment: Here is one way: `n = randam(9,1)`, `b([1:n])`. This correction might be helpful to this problem, thank you

Comment: One correction: `n=randsample(9,1)`

Comment: I must have an old version of Matlab